# php foreach : each link in separate variable

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I get some links from feed with this code on simplepie :

```
 if ($check) :
  foreach ($feed->get_items(0,3) as $item):
  $links = $item->get_permalink();
  echo $links;
 endforeach; endif;
```

thats result me:

```
http://link1....
http://link2....
http://link3....
```

i want to put each link in separate variable like :

```
$links1 = 'http://link1....';
$links1 = 'http://link2....';
$links1 = 'http://link3....';
```

thanks , mori

Comment: I want to show content of each links with "simple_html_dom" after that link retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($feed->get_items(0,3) as $item)) {
    ${'link' . ++$i} = $item->get_permalink();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you want is array variable?

try this:

```
 if ($check) :
   foreach ($feed->get_items(0,3) as $item):
     $links[] = $item->get_permalink();
 endforeach; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($check) :
$i=0;
  foreach ($feed->get_items(0,3) as $item):
  $links.$i = $item->get_permalink();
  echo $links.$i;
$i++;
 endforeach; endif;
```

I think it may works...